# How to output Django form on the browser

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm learning to create a post and comment session with Django and I'm following a tutorial but I don't know why I'm not getting the same result as the one in the tutorial. The post aspect is working but the form for comments is not being displayed on the browser. Even after going through Django documentation and other resources online, I still don't see where I'm getting it wrong. I have the following directories and files:
**start** is my app directory while **education** is the main django directory
start/models.py

```
class Comment (models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name = 'comments', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.Email()
    body = models.TextField()
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['createdAt']
```

start/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class post_comment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'body']
```

start/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import post_comment

def fullPost(request, slug):
    post = Post.object.all()
    return render (request, 'start/start.html', {'post': post})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = post_comment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect ('fullPost', slug=post.slug)
        else: 
            form = post_comment()
        return render (request, 'start/fullPage.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
```

start/templates/start/fullpost.html

```
•••
<h3>Comment</h3>

<form method = 'post' action = '.'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
   <button> Post comment  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: return render (request, 'start/start.html', {'post': post})  => beyond this place, the function does not move

Comment: That was a mistake on my part while typing. I used the right template file`fullPage.html`

Comment: The post_comment is a class above the Meta class which I also omitted

Comment: @Dmitriyl, I tried  `return render (request, start/fullPost.html, {'post': post})` but the form didn't display on the browser still

Comment: `return render (request, 'start/start.html', {'post': post})` start view, line number 7 ... you're returning the post objects.. so the below lines won't execute... that piece of code needs to execute at the end of the method... refer what `return` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the structure of the  fullpost view

In this line:

```
    return render (request, 'start/start.html', {'post': post})
```

the function is exited without the form.
You could try:

start/views.py

```
...
    def fullPost(request, slug):
        post = Post.object.all()
        #return render (request, 'start/start.html', {'post': post})
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = post_comment(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post
                comment.save()
                return redirect ('fullPost', slug=post.slug)
        else: 
            form = post_comment()
        return render (request, 'start/fullPage.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
...
```

If form.is_valid() fails, it will fall through to the end, rendering the form with the incorrect data.

**Edit**
Since you are learning , the following line may be wrong

> ```
> post = Post.object.all()
> ```

because objects.all() retrieves all the posts in the db. Unless you want to comment all posts, you may need to  rewrite it as follows:

> post=Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

This will retrieve the post with the matching slug, assuming the slug field is unique.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get